# How to escape Js file when file_get_contents used, wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am calling a Js file frontend-script from one of the active plugins in my plugin, However, code is running smoothly but when I run a sniffer on my plugin, the sniffer throws an error "All output should be run through an escaping function" found `file_get_contents`. Can anybody help me out?

I have tried:
echo '' . file_get_contents(WC_UBP_URL . '/assets/js/frontend-script.js') . '';
It's working fine, any better solution except this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.